# Multi-threaded Python Web Crawler Got Stuck

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm writing a Python web crawler and I want to make it multi-threaded. Now I have finished the basic part, below is what it does:

1. a thread gets a url from the queue;
2. the thread extracts the links from the page, checks if the links exist in a pool (a set), and puts the new links to the queue and the pool;
3. the thread writes the url and the http response to a csv file.

But when I run the crawler, it always gets stuck eventually, not exiting properly. I have gone through the official document of Python but still have no clue.

Below is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!coding=utf-8

import requests, re, urlparse
import threading
from Queue import Queue
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#custom modules and files
from setting import config


class Page:

    def __init__(self, url):

        self.url = url
        self.status = ""
        self.rawdata = ""
        self.error = False

        r = ""

        try:
            r = requests.get(self.url, headers={'User-Agent': 'random spider'})
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            self.status = e
            self.error = True
        else:
            if not r.history:
                self.status = r.status_code
            else:
                self.status = r.history[0]

        self.rawdata = r

    def outlinks(self):

        self.outlinks = []

        #links, contains URL, anchor text, nofollow
        raw = self.rawdata.text.lower()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(raw)
        outlinks = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

        for link in outlinks:
            d = {"follow":"yes"}
            d['url'] = urlparse.urljoin(self.url, link.get('href'))
            d['anchortext'] = link.text
            if link.get('rel'):
                if "nofollow" in link.get('rel'):
                    d["follow"] = "no"
            if d not in self.outlinks:
                self.outlinks.append(d)


pool = Queue()
exist = set()
thread_num = 10
lock = threading.Lock()
output = open("final.csv", "a")

#the domain is the start point
domain = config["domain"]
pool.put(domain)
exist.add(domain)


def crawl():

    while True:

        p = Page(pool.get())

        #write data to output file
        lock.acquire()
        output.write(p.url+" "+str(p.status)+"\n")
        print "%s crawls %s" % (threading.currentThread().getName(), p.url)
        lock.release()

        if not p.error:
            p.outlinks()
            outlinks = p.outlinks
            if urlparse.urlparse(p.url)[1] == urlparse.urlparse(domain)[1] :
                for link in outlinks:
                    if link['url'] not in exist:
                        lock.acquire()
                        pool.put(link['url'])
                        exist.add(link['url'])
                        lock.release()
        pool.task_done()            


for i in range(thread_num):
    t = threading.Thread(target = crawl)
    t.start()

pool.join()
output.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Marcus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your crawl function has an infinite while loop with no possible exit path. 
The condition `True` always evaluates to `True` and the loop continues, as you say,

> not exiting properly

Modify the crawl function's while loop to include a condition. For instance, when the number of links saved to the csv file exceeds a certain minimum number, then exit the while loop.

i.e.,

```
def crawl():
    while len(exist) <= min_links:
        ...
```

Comment: Hey Cris, xiexie for your quick answer. Do you mean it's because eventually the queue becomes empty but there is still one or more threads trying to get an item from it, so then it got stuck and pool.join() never unblocks?

Comment: No worries, bukerchi. Wow, you are very good at the threading side of things. But no, it is simpler than that. The way python works with this is that as long as your while loop is running, there is not exit from your function. But actually the way you explain it that is true, the calling thread never unblocks because pool continues to run, hence your program freezes, because the calling thread is the main function in this file.